# How to let browser download or open file in a new tab according to what is possible ? (and keep the real file name)

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core, download, asp.net-core-3.1

Here is the situation. In my web application (Angular front-end/.Net Core back-end), I have a page where the user can click on files (stored server-side). When he does, I want the file to open directly in a new tab if allowed by browser (eg : text, images, pdf...). If not allowed, the browser should download the file.

My Angular code looks like this :

```
openFile(fileId: string, name: string) {
    this.httpClient.get('Attachments/Download/' + fileId, { responseType: 'arraybuffer', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }, observe: 'body' }).subscribe(file => {
        if (!file) {
            console.error("file not found.");
            return;
        }

        this.http.get<string>('File/MimeType/' + encodeURIComponent(name)).subscribe(mimetype => {
            if (!mimetype || mimetype === '') {
                console.error("mimetype not found.");
            } else {
                const blob = new Blob([file], { type: mimetype });
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(url, '_blank');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

It's working well except that `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)` renames the files with an ID like `blob:http://my-site/8b92c1b8-72e9-461c-b66c-40a65e705591` (I think I understand why, I've read about it). I also now the to do direct downlad with `<a>`tag and `download` attribute` (here name is fine, but can't open directly in browser).

I just want the browser to make the choice if it's even possible. I'm open to any suggestion. Thanks in advance. :)

EDIT : Feel free to also propose any solution using only backend (.Net Core) but it still needs to open file in a new tab.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really force it to "open a file" after you download it from the webapp, or at least not execute. However i think the solution might be a bit more simple than you think.
Since you know its a file on the server you could just use

`window.open('https://path/to/file.extenstion', '_blank');`

Then it will go to to a new tab and download the file, if your browser have pdf view it will show else it would download. Images would just download as is.

Comment: I was doing this with other projects. You're right, I need to keep it simple. If text file and image are downloaded, I think it's fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

Short answer is you really can't not all browsers behave the same when it comes to files but below is a hacky approach that works for some browsers.

### Setting Filename

Rather than a blob you should use the `File` object because it lets you specify a file name.

```js
const downloadFile = new File([file], name, { type: mimetype }); // using the name variable here
```

#### Hacky Mimetype

I also set the default mimetype to be `application/text` this is a somewhat hacky approach that has the browser download the file as a `.txt` and then opens it from local.

```js
mimetype = "application/text"
```

While the url won't have the filename, the resulting download will be named appropriately.

### clearing the url

I noticed you aren't revoking the url for this download which is unsafe and holds a reference to the blob.
You should revoke it like so

```js
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

#### Final Composition

```js
file = ""
name = "document.pdf"
mimetype = "application/text"
const downloadFile = new File([file], name, { type: mimetype }); 
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url, '_blank');
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Life example: https://codepen.io/w-b/pen/VwXXjdL

More on the file constructor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though it seems that it's not workinf either (exact same results).  Can you maybe provide a working example ? :)

Comment: i updated my answer with some changes and included a life example with codepen @KBell

Comment: Just tested. For me, your codepen works well in Chrome and Firefox. Using your code in my app does not work though. In Chrome, it keeps downloading file with ID instead of name and the file loses extension. In Firefox, browser asks to accept popup (which would be acceptable) and works well with PDF, but not with image for example.
I think there's no real good solution unfortunately. I'll probably have to handle all this directly from back-end. :/ Anyway thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I did open file (PDF, TXT, DOXC, ...) But Click and open file in the modal.

If you want click `open file` and target `_blank`. You try this way

Don't forget package: `ngx-doc-viewer`

1. you can create a `show_attachment` component.
2. Click `openFile()` and call `ShowAttachmentComponent`

show_attachment.component.ts

```
@Input path: string;
@Input minitype: string;


  isDocx(mimetype) {
    return mimetype.includes('wordprocessingml.document') || mimetype.includes('msword');
  }

  isXlsx(mimetype) {
    return mimetype.includes('spreadsheetml.sheet') || mimetype.includes('application/vnd.ms-excel') || mimetype.includes('application/excel');
  }

  isPowerPoint(mimetype) {
    return mimetype.includes('presentation') || mimetype.includes('powerpoint');
  }

  isCSV(mimetype) {
    return mimetype.includes('text/csv') || mimetype.includes('text/comma-separated-values');
  }

  isTxt(mimetype) {
    return mimetype.includes('text/plain');
  }
```

show_attachment.component.html

```
     <div class="show-detail" *ngIf="getIsImage(this.mimetype)">
            <img [src]="path"/>
        </div>      
        <div class="show-detail doc-content" *ngIf="isDocx(this.mimetype) || isXlsx(data.detail.external_video_type) || isPowerPoint(this.mimetype)">
            <ngx-doc-viewer [url]="path" viewer="office" style="width:100%;height:80vh;">
            </ngx-doc-viewer>
        </div>
        <div class="show-detail other-content" *ngIf="isTxt(this.mimetype)">
            <ngx-doc-viewer [url]="path" viewer="url" style="width:100%;height:80vh;">
            </ngx-doc-viewer>
        </div>
```

Comment: Seems to be a decent solution, though I'll try to avoid adding new dependency to the project if possible. Thanks for your answer.